# Convert Dollar Data from Character to Numeric

Tags: r

How would I change a column that has character data in the format of "33 dollars 14 cents" to numeric data formatted like"33.14"?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stringr` library to extract the numeric components and then paste them together.  This assumes that there are always only two numbers for the format you are looking for.

```
library(stringr)

s <- c("33 dollars 14 cents", "35 dollars 50 cents")

sapply(str_extract_all(s,"\\d+"), function(x) paste(x, collapse = "."))

[1] "33.14" "35.50"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `sub`

```
x <- "33 dollars 14 cents" 
as.numeric(sub("^(\\d+)\\s+dollars\\s+(\\d+)\\s+cents$", "\\1.\\2", x))
# [1] 33.14
as.numeric(sub("^(\\d+).*?(\\d+).*", "\\1.\\2", x))
# [1] 33.14
```

or

```
as.numeric(paste(str_extract_all(x, "\\d+")[[1]], collapse="."))
# [1] 33.14
```

Comment: I'm curious where you learnt all these string searching regular expressions. They are super useful and I haven't found a good source, can you point me somewhere? (Then my answers can be more refined!) Cheers!

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger I love to do string operations. You know 90% of string operations should be done using regex. I learned all the regex stuffs from this site (SO) only. If you have any doubts in regex, feel free to ping me from anyone of the chat room. I usually cool myself inside GMT room.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for the help! I'm curious if you can run this for an entire vector rather than the first element only?

Comment: Why? is this won't work for you? Pls post the exact input.

Comment: I think i phrased my comment wrong. This works great for what I am looking for, I just need to apply it to an entire column in my data set rather than just the first element. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is all the same format you can use `gsub()`.

This is clumsy but it works:

`as.numeric(gsub(" cents","",gsub(" dollars ",".",data)))`

Answer (score 0):

It's always worthwhile to write a simple function to handle cases where you need several little steps. Here's a non-elegant example that's easy to read;

```
numerify <- function(x) {# convert string in form of "33 dollars 14 cents" to numeric 33.14
 x <- gsub('[a-z]','',x) # remove letters
 x <- gsub(' $','',x)    # remove trailing space
 x <- gsub(' +','.',x)   # insert decimal point
 return(as.numeric(x))   # convert to numeric
}
```